# Doubts related to some assumption of kinetic theory

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

I have doubts related to the kinetic theory of gases which are mostly conceptual which I cannot find in my textbooks.

1. How assumptions the molecules to be perfectly rigid and spherical be good since we know that they look somewhat like a dumbbell?
2. We say that the rotational kinetic energy of the molecules can be ignored because of their small size and negligible moment of inertia
   but the question is why the molecules are spinning.
3. How can the assumption that collision per unit volume be the same is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)how assumption the molecules to be perfectly rigid and spherical be
> good since we know that they looks somewhat to dumbbell

Whether the gas molecule is diatomic (looks like a dumbbell as you say) monatomic (e.g., helium, neon, argon, etc..) or other has nothing to do with the assumption that an ideal gas experiences only elastic collisions. The atoms of the molecule are assumed to be rigid spheres and the bonds between the atoms of a diatomic , triatomic etc. molecule, are assumed to be perfectly elastic (like ideal springs).

What does matter, however, are the number of different degrees of freedom of motion which determines rotational and vibrational modes of kinetic energy of the molecule.

> 2. we say that the rotational kinetic energy of the molecules can be
>    ignored because of their small size and negligible moment of inertia
>    but the question is why the molecules be spinning

The rotational kinetic energy can only be ignored for monatomic gases. For such gases the molecules are considered to be points. Points have no dimensions and therefore have no rotational moment of inertia. Points do not "spin".

> 3)how can the assumption that collision per unit volume be same good

I assume you are referring to "collision frequency", or collisions per unit volume per unit time. But I'm not sure what assumption you are referring to. For an equation for collision frequency between atoms or molecules of an ideal gas, look up the Wikipedia article on "Collision Frequency".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks i am slowly understanding kinetic theory now